# Ternary operator if...elsif...else attempt Ruby

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator

Why isn't this working. I am attempting to refactor the code to use the smallest number of characters possible..

```
for i in 1..200                                    # 33
 if (i%3 == 0)                                     # 34
    if (i%5 == 0) ? puts "FizzBuzz" : puts 'Fizz'  # 35
   end                                             # 36
 elsif (i%5 == 0) ? puts "FizzBuzz"                # 37
   if (i%3 == 0)                                   # 38
   else puts "Buzz"                                # 39
   end                                             # 40
 else puts i                                       # 41
 end                                               # 42
end                                                # 43
```

Comment: what is your error

Comment: `numberGame.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
     if (i%5 == 0) ? puts "FizzBuzz" : puts 'Fizz'` - That's the first of 5 errors

Comment: When using 'if' the actions should be between the 'if'/'elif'/'else' line and the 'end'.  You will have other errors besides those related to ternary operator

Comment: Ternary is `x ? y : z`. Not `if x ? y : z`.

Comment: @Mohammad do you have a working version of that code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use nested if-else you can use

```
(1..200).each do |num|
  if (num%3 == 0 && num%5 == 0)
    puts "BucksFizz"
  elsif num%3 == 0
    puts "Bucks"
  elsif num%5 == 0
    puts "Fizz"
  elsif 
    puts num 
  end          
end
```

Answer (score 1):

use `puts  i%5 == 0 ? "FizzBuzz" :'Fizz'`

instead of `if (i%5 == 0) ? puts "FizzBuzz" : puts 'Fizz'`

Do this for all such statements